# Log / Debug Process CSV Import Product - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am doing tests with the importer of products in CSV and for several days it worked well, but today I added 10 new products and I get this error when importing:

[image: capture error]

Where can I see a log with the exact error? Or failing, how can I debug the import process to see the error?

And another thing, where you can suggest for future versions that the errors in the import are a little more explanatory ?.

Thank you.

Comment: Active error in your store and post result

Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend you to change the memory_limit from 128M to 512M.

I had the same problem and now it works fine.

Comment: Sorry for not answer before. I post the solution (the same like you) some days ago in the oficial forum of prestashop: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/599549-log-debug-process-csv-import-product-prestashop-17/

Finally I find the problem. Was a big image (5000x5000 pixels) that broken php with function imagecreatefromjpeg().
 
The solution was update 'memory_limit' in php.ini from 128M to 512M.

Comment: Although by chance it may fix OP's particular issue, this answer is rather a comment, since it doesn't address the question at all.